# ant debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I would like to know about the debugging capabilities of ANT using eclipse. Basically
I have an ANT build script written by a colleague and I wanted to step
through each target to see what are the various tasks that are beings
called.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380429/debug-ant-task-from-eclipse

Answer (score 35):

You can do this in Eclipse with these steps:

1. Be sure to open your build file in
   the ANT editor (right click on build
   file -> Open with -> Ant editor).
2. Double click in the left margin of
   your build file where you want
   breakpoint.
3. Open the Ant view (Window -> Show
   view -> Ant).
4. If the build file isn't in the view
   then you can simply add it.
5. Once added right click on the ant
   target you want to run and select Debug as ->
   Ant build
6. The Debug perspective should open up
   and the process should stop at your
   breakpoint where you can step
   through it
7. Sometimes it is required to set the arguments at the time of debugging. It can be set by selecting: Debug as -> Ant build. And then need to select Arguments. And then values can be entered as:  -Dprop.name=property value

Answer (score 8):

Create a script `antdebug.sh` which sets the environment variable `ANT_OPTS`before starting ant

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
export ANT_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=2607"
# now execute ant
exec ant "$@"
```

Afterwards you can remote attach to it using your IDE. Please note the `suspend=y`, it will suspend the execution until you are attached.

Answer (score 4):

Since ant is just a Java application, you can just add a debug configuration (type Java Application) to eclipse.  See [Running Ant via Java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava) for how to invoke Ant as if it were a Java application.  I'll assume you know how to debug a Java app in Eclipse, so that should get you the rest of the way.  If not, ask and I'll expand on this.

Answer (score 4):

With large ant files, or large java projects, when we may have multiple ant files calling each other, I've found that a dependency graph is very useful. I've used [Grand](https://github.com/Ant-Grand/Grand) to this purpose.

Of course, this will not help much if you want to debug the sequence of instructions inside a particular target.

Answer (score 2):

Before you dive deep into Ant internals, it may be worth trying to run the script with -d (debug) flag and observe the output. Assuming that you are interested in understand how the particular Ant script is working (or not working) and not Ant itself.

If Ant is your area of interest, the answers above are the direction to follow.

Answer (score 1):

add below xml tag to ant `build.xml` after target init

```
<javac srcdir="${src.java.dir}" destdir="${target.build.dir}" includeantruntime="true" source="${source}" target="${target}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" classpathref="main.classpath" fork="true" memoryinitialsize="512m" memorymaximumsize="512m" />
```

if the javac is already there make sure to add `debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source"` to have a interactive debug session.