# Debugging ant based projects with the sonar ant task

Tags: debugging, ant, sonarqube

How can I debug the execution of the sonar ant task (**ant sonar**) in eclipse. Maven based projects could be debugged with **mvnDebug sonar**. Is there a similar way for ant based projects?. I know for the **java** task exists the **jvmarg** elements, but I failed routing those through the sonar-task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ant debugging in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039933/ant-debugging-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out this question was some how answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3040047/1164553. So the solution is an invocation like this:

```
java -cp $ANT_HOME/lib/ant-launcher.jar 
 -Dant.home=$ANT_HOME 
 -Xdebug -Xnoagent 
 -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
 org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher 
 sonar
```