# Does Intellij IDEA support debugging a project built with ant?

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea, build

This project is using Ant as its build system. Can I debug the project when I run it via Ant?

Comment: Ant has nothing to do with it. Ant is a build tool. Debugging is at run time.

Comment: @BoristheSpider if you are working with a complex buildfile, debugging it step by step could help you to understand how is it actually building your project.

Comment: I'm a big fan of IntelliJ IDEA but specifically for this task Eclipse does a great job

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ant** is mainly used for building, not for running **Java** apps.
But OK, I assume you're running your app using the **ant** **Java** task.

[Ant Java task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

If so, yes, you can do that by using remote debugging.

[Remote debugging a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

In fact you can debug any **Java** app like that.
Apps started through **ant** are still **Java** apps.

Comment: Oh of course! I shouldn't be running my app through ant, just building the app. This is exactly what the knowledge I needed. Thank you.

Comment: And how do you add the agentlib when running an ant task? I can't see a place to specify JVM arguments. Edit: Ah I see, right click the Ant task in the "Ant Build" panel, `Properties`, `Execution`, `Ant command line`

Answer (score 2):

Include this line in your java runtime task, in your build.xml:

```
<jvmarg value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"/>
```

So for instance if it's ant junit task, it will be like:

```
<target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit showoutput="yes" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Then run your target

```
ant clean test
```

Ant test will wait until we connect a debugger. It will show the output:

```
test:
    [junit] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Then simply create, run a remote run/debug configuration in [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-remote.html) (or in your preferred IDE).

Answer (score 1):

There is a specialized IDEA plugin for debugging ant scripts sources with breakpoints:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7195?pr=idea

https://github.com/opticyclic/antdebugger/

Or the same approach can be used as for [ant debugging in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039933/ant-debugging-in-eclipse).

Comment: Isn't this to debug just buiild.xml?

Comment: @reversiblean, yes, this answer is about debugging ant scripts in build.xml, not the project that is built with them. It appears, I was tricked by vague wording of the question.